# Flowplayer Overlay - Change target selector

Tags: jquery, html, overlay, flowplayer

After reading some topics and replies in the Flowplayer Forum, I figured out that you guys might be a better help for my problem.

As you may know the [Flowplayer overlay plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) uses the `rel` attribute to target a specific overlay container. For example:

```
<a href="#" id="signup" rel="#signupOverlay"></a>

$("#signup[rel]").overlay({
    mask: {
        color: '#000',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    }
});
```

I would really like not to use the `rel` attribute, but the HTML5 data attribute instead.

So it would look like this:

```
<a href="#" id="signup" data-overlay="#signupOverlay"></a>

$("#signup[data-overlay]").overlay({
    mask: {
        color: '#000',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

So, I have also tried to change following line in the plugin code: `var n=e.target||d.attr("rel");` to `var n=e.target||d.attr("data-overlay");`

But this also doesn't work.

If any1 of you maybe already had this problem before and solved it, I would be glad to hear how!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#signup").live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default link action
    var $href = $(this).attr('data-overlay');
    $(this).overlay({
        target: $href,
        load: true
        });
});
```

I haven't tested like that, but I have adapted it from a code that I use with href instead of data-overlay and it works. I guess that will work too.